# c4.5 algorithm implementation on *nix

Tags: algorithm, unix, implementation

I am trying to compile and execute the [c4.5 algorithm](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ml/dtrees/c4.5/tutorial.html) on my mac os machine (have a red hat enterprise linux 4.6 machine too), but have not been able to get anywhere with the same.

Is there any one who has tried this and succeed on getting the same to compile and execute on their machines? If, so, please can you share the steps?

Comment: Let us know what you've tried, and what went wrong. Otherwise, we're just guessing what problems you had. Did it work on the RH machine? The page you link to has instructions. How far did you get through them before it went wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get this to compile, add

```
#define cfree    free
```

into R8/Src/defns.i and change line 51 of R8/Src/average.c to

```
if ( i != Numbers ) exit(1);
```

(i.e. pass 1 to the exit command). Apart from that follow the website instructions (i.e. open terminal, extract with tar xvzf, compile by typing "cd R8/Src; make all").

If this should not help, post more details as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), it's a data mining tool, and it contain C4.5 (aka J48 in Weka's naming). It's written in Java, and should work on any recent JVM.

I know it doesn't really answer to your question, but I had hard time running C4.5 myself, and using it through weka was much *much* easier